# Accessing docker container running in remote linux machine from a windows browser

Tags: linux, docker, containers, remote-access

I have a remote ubuntu machine with docker installed and a container is running on that,  i want to access it from my windows machine through a browser,  i can connect to the ubuntu remote machine from my windows machine through putty,  is there any way, i would be able to achieve this,  any helps or leads in this case will be highly appreciated?

Comment: Any diagnostic report? What port have you exposed? Have you checked/adjusted the firewall settings of your server? can you print the output of the running containers with the commands docker ps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the container, you'll need to publish the port that you want to connect to using the -p flag. Here's an example from the Docker documentation that publishes port 80 in the container to port 80 on the host (you can map to a different port if you'd like):

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 my_image service nginx start
```

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports